# How do you capitalize just the first letter in PySpark for a dataset? (Simple capitalization/sentence case)

Tags: python, pyspark, dataset, field, capitalize

I need to clean several fields: species/description are usually a simple capitalization in which the first letter is capitalized. PySpark only has upper, lower, and initcap (every single word in capitalized) which is not what I'm looking for. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html

Python has a native capitalize() function which I have been trying to use but keep getting an incorrect call to column.

```
fields_to_cap = ['species', 'description']

for col_name in fields_to_cap:
    df = df.withColumn(col_name, df[col_name].captilize())
```

Is there a way to easily capitalize these fields?

To be clear, I am trying to capitalize the data within the fields. Here is an example:

Current:
"tHis is a descripTion."

Expected:
"This is a description."

Comment: what is df exactly because my code just works fine

Comment: is this the full code because you didn't define df yet

Comment: Hi Greg, this is not the full code but a snippet. df is my input dataframe that is already defined and called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a workaround by splitting the first letter and the rest, make the first letter uppercase and lowercase the rest, then concatenate them back

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 'rush HouR'],
                            [2, 'kung-Fu Panda'],
                            [3, 'titaniC'],
                            [4, 'the Sixth sense']], schema="id int, title string")

df = df.withColumn('title_capitalize', F.concat(F.upper(F.expr("substring(title, 1, 1)")), 
                                                F.lower(F.expr("substring(title, 2)"))))
df.show()

+---+---------------+----------------+
| id|          title|title_capitalize|
+---+---------------+----------------+
|  1|      rush HouR|       Rush hour|
|  2|  kung-Fu Panda|   Kung-fu panda|
|  3|        titaniC|         Titanic|
|  4|the Sixth sense| The sixth sense|
+---+---------------+----------------+
```

or you can use a UDF if you want to stick using Python's `.capitalize()`

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

udf_capitalize  = F.udf(lambda x: str(x).capitalize(), StringType())

df = df.withColumn('title_capitalize', udf_capitalize('title'))
```

Answer (score 11):

Use [`initcap`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.initcap.html#pyspark.sql.functions.initcap)

```
data = [
  (1001, 'jana', 'yes'),
  (1001, 'Jleo', 'no')
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['SID','species', 'description']).show()

+----+-------+-----------+
| SID|species|description|
+----+-------+-----------+
|1001|   jana|        yes|
|1001|   Jleo|         no|
+----+-------+-----------+


from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.withColumn("species", initcap(col('species'))).withColumn("description", initcap(col('description'))).show()

+----+-------+-----------+
| SID|species|description|
+----+-------+-----------+
|1001|   Jana|        Yes|
|1001|   Jleo|         No|
+----+-------+-----------+
```